# Obtaining the maximum value with Order By and Limit 1

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, I am using MySQL. When I make the following query:

```
SELECT CodE,sum(tiempo) AS 'tiempo total' 
FROM Participa 
GROUP BY CodE
ORDER BY 'tiempo total' DESC LIMIT 1;
```

it shows me the first line of my table instead of the MAX value. However, If I make the following query:

```
SELECT CodE,sum(tiempo) 
FROM Participa
GROUP BY CodE 
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

I get the correct result.
I have just changed the alias 'tiempo total' for somthing that should be equivalent.

How it´s possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use single quotes for string and date constants -- never for column aliases.  So:

```
SELECT CodE, sum(tiempo) AS `tiempo total`
FROM Participa 
GROUP BY CodE
ORDER BY `tiempo total` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You are ordering by a constant string, not the name of a column.  Hence, if you get the maximum in your query, it would be a total accident.

Note:  You can get around these issues by giving columns names that never need to be escaped:

```
SELECT CodE, sum(tiempo) AS tiempo_total
FROM Participa 
GROUP BY CodE
ORDER BY tiempo_total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Easier to type, too.

Comment: So, it is impossible to order by an Alias made by 2 words and a space between them? What I mean is that I can never use an alias like `tiempo total`

Comment: What is the different between my first example and yours?

Comment: @SergioCavero . . . The quotes are correct in my version.